# more then 1 query per PHP document

Tags: php, mysql

For a webpage im using data from mysql to display in charts etc.

For each query that gives me data from mysql i have a seperate php document. is it possible to store more then one query in a php doc instead of creating a new php for every query?

If so, how do i change this getJSON request (because as it is now it uses the whole php doc instead of the specific query i want to use)

```
department = $("#department").val();
            hospital = $("#hospital").val();

            //console.log('changed'); 
            $.getJSON('functions/charts_hospital.php', {
                "hosp":hospital,
                "dept":department},
```

I want to use the department and hospital variable in different queries within 1 php document..

Thnaks in advance,

Bart

Comment: That `AJAX` request does not "use a php doc", there is no such thing. It uses (proccesses) whatever response that php _script_ outputs. You can output  a single array holding the results of a single query. But nothing speaks against posting an array that holds the result of many queries. You just have to use a structure so that your processing logic on the client side is able to tell them apart...

Comment: In addition you'd have to post the code for the charts_hospital.php script for us to show you how to do that. 

Where are you having problems? Have you tried running 2 queries in that script?

Comment: running two queries is not the issue, but both queries give me different JSON data. How do keep these two arrays seperate form eachother?

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a solution:

Within the `getJSON()` I put another variable called `functionName` I use this variable to determine which function should be called from the PHP file. Within these functions is use my other variables. Each function returns the desired data.

All the functions are within one PHP file. So that saves me a lot of other PHP files.